# An error occured while instantiating the class LoginPageTest. Check to make sure it can be instantiated

Tags: java

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class LoginPageTest. Check to make sure it can be instantiated
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

These are the below classes that has been created:
in src/main/java:

```
public class BaseClass {
    
    protected WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    public static BaseClass browserInvoke = null;
    
    public static BaseClass getInstance() {
        if (browserInvoke == null) {
            browserInvoke = new BaseClass();
        }
        return browserInvoke;
    }
    
    
    public BaseClass(){
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/mydocuments/src/main/java/com/mycode/qa/config/config.prop");
            prop.load(ip);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    public void initialization() {
        
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if(browserName.equals("Chrome")) {
             
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
             driver = new ChromeDriver();     
        } 
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT));
        
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        
    }
    
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    
}
```

Page objects in LoginPage:

```
public class LoginPage extends BaseClass{
    
    @FindBy(name="email")
    WebElement email;
    
    @FindBy(name="password")
    WebElement password;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='submit']//*")
    WebElement signinbutton;
    
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    
    }
    
    public String validateLoginPagetitle() {
        
        return driver.getTitle();
        
    }
    
    public nextPage login(String mail,String pwd) {
        
        email.sendKeys(mail);
        password.sendKeys(pwd);
        signinbutton.click();
        
        return new nextpage();
    }
    

}
```

in src/main/test:

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BaseClass{
    
    LoginPage loginPage;
    NextPage nextPage;
    
    public LoginPageTest(WebDriver driver) {
        super();
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        
        driver = BaseClass.getInstance().getDriver();
        initialization();
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);      
    }
    
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void loginPageTitleTest() throws Exception {
        String title = loginPage.validateLoginPagetitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Google");
    }
    
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void loginTest()throws Exception {
        nextPage = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("email"),prop.getProperty("password"));
        
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
        
    }
    
    

}
```

All the recommended classes have been imported. Please help

Comment: My best guess is that you haven't told `TestNG` how to provide that `WebDriver` parameter. That's why it can't instantiate your test class. And since you're initializing it in another way as well, you probably just forgot to remove it from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not worked with TestNG closely, but *my guess* is that TestNG is unable to instantiate the `LoginPageTest` becuase it has a constructor with an argument. It simply does not know from where to get the instance of the `WebDriver`. So you should either remove this parameter or make sure the TestNG knows where to get it from.